# Active Discharge Options

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor-charging

More and more frequently I am faced with a specification that requires the ability to discharge an output capacitance to a safe level X, in time Y. The circuit I am currently working on is 2000uF @ 600V (roughly 300J). It needs to discharge to 30V in 2 seconds. I can accomplish this with a few resistors and a FET in series with an average power dissipation of 180W over the 2 second discharge time, but I feel like there is a better way.

Does anyone know any alternative active discharge methods?

Thank you

Comment: A 3kW array of 300W Halogen bulbs?

Comment: Note that at the beginning, the capacitive element will have higher resistance and hence discharge at a higher current, which is why something that is easy to make hard against burning under peak load is probably clever. Don't know if @SunnyskyguyEE75's halogen lamps are really optimal in that light (hehe, pun.).

Comment: @MarcusMüller  If you string 120 or 240V bulbs in series then they act as  PTC current sinks http://tinyurl.com/yxnln2me

Comment: Space is tight, roughly 3U (a little over 5"), so halogens are out. It is a lot of instantaneous power, but a very low average power. Duty cycle is 2s every 60s or 3%.

Comment: most any material (silicon, resistive) with a few cubic inches of volume to store the heat ----- will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define 'better' before anybody can suggest a better way.

You have 360 Joules to get rid of.

The easy way is to turn it into heat. 360J is not much, in terms of the thermal pulse capacity of a large metal element resistor. Calculate the right size, switch it across your capacitor, it will heat up, job done. This is likely to be the cheapest, most reliable, least fussy way to do it, all of which says 'better'.

'Metal element'? It could be a wirewound resistor, it could be a halogen bulb. The latter has the advantage that it can heat to 2000+ degrees, far hotter than a resistor, so can be smaller. But it's glass packaged, not as easy to mount as a 'resistor'.

There are other materials you could dissipate power in, like silicon. But metal is cheaper and more robust. Water resistors are great for very high powers, but they're messy, and not something you would want on a board.

There are other things you could do with the energy, like recover it to somewhere else. That's more complicated and expensive, and I'm not sure 360J is worth the bother.

Comment: In my last design (4F @ 30V ~ 1kJ) I used 4 ceramic resistors mounted to a heatsink as the dissipation element. There was a decent amount of cabling between the cap bank and the discharger so I wanted as little additional inductance as possible.

By "better" I was looking for a more efficient way, but since all of the energy is wasted as heat no matter what I do, that isn't an achievable goal.

Answer (score 0):

## The [Halogen bulb method.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.000155%2030.13683688681966%2055%205%2050%0A209%2048%20256%2048%20288%200%200.002%200.000021607363702034657%201%0Ag%2048%20304%2048%20328%200%0Aw%20-24%2056%20-88%2056%203%0Av%20-88%2088%20-88%2056%200%200%2040%20600%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2048%20288%2048%20304%200%200.01%0Aw%2048%20256%2048%20240%203%0A181%2048%2072%2048%20128%200%20303.4615627267945%20300%20230%200.4%200.4%0AS%2048%2072%20-24%2072%200%200%20false%200%202%0Aw%20-88%2088%20-24%2088%200%0Ag%20-88%2088%20-88%20104%200%0Ax%20107%20163%20211%20166%204%2016%20300W%5Cs230V%5Csx3%0Ax%2088%20312%20120%20315%204%2016%20ESR%0A181%2048%20128%2048%20184%200%20303.4615627267945%20300%20230%200.4%200.4%0A181%2048%20184%2048%20240%200%20303.4615627267945%20300%20230%200.4%200.4%0Ao%205%2064%200%2020746%20640%200.1%200%202%205%203%0Ao%206%2064%207%2020746%205%200.1%200%201%205120%0Ao%204%2064%200%2020745%205%2025.6%200%202%204%203%0A)

Cold Resistance is 10% of R(hot)=V²/W rating of bulb.  Thus surge current is V/R(cold) but that is normal for tungsten lamps. Chose bulb voltage and power for desired current or power limit or time constant.
[Sim](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.000155%2069.34413510434165%2055%205%2050%0A209%2048%20256%2048%20288%200%200.002%208.305394646381057e-14%201%0Ag%2048%20304%2048%20328%200%0Aw%20-24%2056%20-88%2056%203%0Av%20-88%2088%20-88%2056%200%200%2040%20600%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2048%20288%2048%20304%200%200.01%0Aw%2048%20256%2048%20240%203%0A181%2048%2072%2048%20128%200%20300.24054887373785%20300%20230%200.4%200.4%0AS%2048%2072%20-24%2072%200%200%20false%200%202%0Aw%20-88%2088%20-24%2088%200%0Ag%20-88%2088%20-88%20104%200%0Ax%2082%20162%20186%20165%204%2016%20300W%5Cs230V%5Csx3%0Ax%2088%20312%20120%20315%204%2016%20ESR%0A181%2048%20128%2048%20184%200%20300.24054887373785%20300%20230%200.4%200.4%0A181%2048%20184%2048%20240%200%20300.24054887373785%20300%20230%200.4%200.4%0Ao%205%2064%200%2020746%20640%200.1%200%202%205%203%0Ao%206%2064%207%2020746%205%200.1%200%201%205120%0Ao%204%2064%200%2020745%205%2025.6%200%202%204%203%0A)

[image]
2.4A peak current, < 2 seconds.
Without specs, there is no clear advantage.

If downvoting indicate what spec does this solution not meet?  [You can also use a 1500W Halogen](http://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/conventional-lamps-and-tubes/halogen-lamps/mv-halogen-without-reflector/plusline-large/923932243241_EU/product)   11mm x 255mm 230V